# Typescript - Narrowing T[K] in a function when multiple key values are passed in

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm attempting to write a hook that accepts multiple keys of an object and filters down the data based on currently applied filters. So, something along the lines of this:

```
interface IFilterable<T,K extends keyof T & string>{
  key: K;
  customFilter?: (item: T[K], applied: T[K][]) => boolean
  //The hook uses some default logic to filter if this function isn't available.
}

function useFilters<T,K extends keyof T & string>(data: T[], filters: IFilterable<T,K>[]): T[]{
 //filter out the data, return new dataset.
}
```

The issue is that when multiple filters (`IFilterable`) are passed in, the `item` and `applied` parameters in the `customFilter` function becomes the union of the types of the keys. Or, in code...

```
useFilters(
  [{a: 1, b: "bob"], {a: 2, b: "berry"}],
  [{key: "a", customFilter: (item, applied) => {
    //Wanted: item has the type number
    //Reality: item has the type (string | number)
  }, 
  {key: "b", customFilter: (item, applied) => {
    //Wanted: item has the type string.
    //Reality: item has the type (string | number)
  }
}]);
```

I have "solved" the problem by typing everything as `unknown`(or `unknown[]`) and then creating wrapper functions that cast things back to the proper type later, but I want to keep things strongly typed the whole way through if possible.

So, is there any way in cases like this, where I am passing in array of objects where one property is a key and another property is a function that takes `T[K]`, to narrow to the type of a specific `T[K]` instead of the union type?

Thanks.

Comment: Interface for IFilterable is wrong. TS has not tuple type like (item: T[K], applied: T[K][])

Comment: @captain-yossarian It's a function that returns a boolean... I forgot to add the return type there. Updated the original post.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 17 September 2021**

I made my homework.

Consider this example:

```js
/**
 * Obtain a union of all values of a dictionary
 */
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type FilterBuilder<T extends any[]> = Values<{
  [Key in keyof T[number]]: {
    key: Key,
    customFilter: (item: T[number][Key], applied: T[number][Key][]) => void
  }
}>

{
  //   type Test = {
  //     key: "a";
  //     customFilter: (item: 1, applied: 1[]) => void;
  // } | {
  //     key: "b";
  //     customFilter: (item: "str", applied: "str"[]) => void;
  // }
  type Test = FilterBuilder<[{ a: 1, b: 'str' }]>
}

const withFilters = <
  Item extends Record<PropertyKey, unknown>,
  Items extends Item[],
  >(data: [...Items]) => <
    Filter extends FilterBuilder<Items>,
    Filters extends Filter[],
    >(filters: [...Filters]) => { }

const useFilters = withFilters([{ a: 1, b: "bob" }, { a: 2, b: "berry" }])

const result = useFilters(
  [{
    key: "a", customFilter: (item, applied) => { }
  },
  {
    key: "b", customFilter: (item, applied) => { }
  }]
);
```

It is hard for typescript to infer the `key` of object and apply this type immediately to another property of same object, at least in this case.

Hence, I just created a union of all allowed `key/customFilter` filters pairs.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhFgCgAIWh5ARgFwIYEsB21XQK6boD22RAZjgDaXQBuqleApgM7Tk7QAm6AxssUyoATgE8osYFGSiADk2gA1BsxYAeACoA+aAF5oGgNoBrJqI4aAulGlyFAMXSVkTYQCE8Trq83QmADxdMLjZUTFFDSx19ZUZWNQBvCWhDAGkzaCxoU3MKI0w8AFtEV0tLAC5oJJhoWpzK9NEAGmTa3jwWZCJCx2dXSoAKdBdCyvyikuFLNLNLJpxZWUp0Ji4xwwLi0pnRacsASj0dWiJ0LmSAXygLrRtIatrgYFroGXkDVmQ9KuSnl7qzJUAESoIEAbl+z3+7U63V6LmEg2GTFG0AAjPNUItlqtKmjIoddMdTlwITU-hdoAAfH7kqEverQIGIcGQ-7QGFdHpOBFIkbAzrCIGY7ErNZMwVAglHOgksmPZ5XGpvBQaT7feGuDxeHyGBI4PHzRCVADkgpN0AuUWud14JE60AA7sMABaa4RsfRqZIASRGfkCTGCbAASkw7cIuGoAArCIjyYQyRrzAjGTBER2YLQtGp+lFsAJBELQPOFSI52paAZcVBoSqGAB0TdLLAOMu9NVq7oDRbY7u1lG8wjULezrWg7oLgeDE55rnL46rZDnHvrTYbk7bRKqltt9q+HSYk++zuQbpXLAGeoN6KNwMQRBZlvm+tQlQATHemZMxEDLQc90wB1hFYPBnG+Q9JwGZI9XHRkQWFDkOi5d0+RREUljFQkdH1JVaguCtaX+eCWXmTk4RXNDCgwnEuGwnc8P-KB9jBIA)

**`Values`** - creates a union of all values of the dictionary data structure

**`FilterBuilder`**:

1. iterates over each key of elements which exists in the tuple `T`.
2. creates a new object for iterated key with `key` and `customFilter` props.
3. Where `customFilter` is a function with two arguments: `item` - value of iterated object, `applied` - array of values of iterated object

**`withFilters`**: is a curried function. It expects a tuple of objects which we are interested in and returns function which expects an array of `FilterBuilder` results. `FilterBuilder` just returns a discriminated union of all allowed states of `key/customFilter` object.

Comment: Sorry, but this really doesn't answer my question. I'm aware of _why_ it happens, but limiting to one key isn't what I want to do - the point is to be able to pass in multiple keys, with different filtering functions, to narrow down the original dataset.

What I'm looking for is if there is a way to narrow T[K] when there are multiple K values, so that each `customFilter` function would be typed properly with the key it's grouped with.

Comment: @ChristopherOpiela made an update