# Infer type based on the generic type of a sibling property in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to define the type of a property based on the generic type of its sibling property.

for example, assume we have:

```js
type Person = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

type Select<Value=unknown> = (props:Props<Value>) => any;

const PersonSelect:Select<Person> = (props) => null //implementation is irrelavant
const TextSelect:Select<string> = (props) => null //implementation is irrelavant
```

then I want to be able to do something like this:

```js
type Filter<V = unknown > = {
  component: Select<V>,
  transformer: (value: V) => string
};

const filters:Array<Filter> = [
  {
    component: PersonSelect,
    transformer: (selected) => selected.name //type of `selected` should be infered as `Person`
  },
  {
    component: TextSelect,
    transformer: (selected) => selected // type of `selected` should be infered as `string`
  }
]
```

**Workaround**

With the above code I can do it like

```js
const personFilter:Filter<Person> = {
    component: PersonSelect,
    transformer: (selected) => selected.name
}
const textFilter:Filter<string> = {
    component: TextSelect,
    transformer: (selected) => selected
}

const filters = [personFilter, textFilter];
```

But I'm looking for a solution that works without explicitly defining the type of each filter object. Also, the generic `V` type can be anything, so I can't use the union of all possible combinations.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: What's `Props`? The deprecated interface from React?

Comment: No, I just wanted to show that the `Value` is actually used in the type of `Select`. it could be something like  `type Props<V> = { value: V; onChange: (value:V) => void; }` and was removed from the code for simplicity

Comment: Very similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63708358/typescript-narrowing-tk-in-a-function-when-multiple-key-values-are-passed-in/63710980#63710980

Comment: Let me know if it works for you tsplay.dev/NBPOdW

Comment: Please keep in mind, if you want to pass `filters` to some component as a prop. Typings will be slightly different. Then you need to infer that array from component level

Comment: @captain-yossarian Thanks, but your approach is depending on tuples, so I have to keep the order of filter objects the same as their corresponding type in the tuple. I'm looking for something more general if possible

Comment: I think simpliest solution would be to create `FIlter` builder function, like here tsplay.dev/mx5rGW . Does it work for you?

Comment: @captain-yossarian Yeah, this is exactly what I needed. Please post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be TypeScript having hard time to infer arrow function property argument based on other property of same object.

I was unable to do it with help of function inference.

The most simplest way is to make `builder` function which returns `Filter<_>`.

```js
type Person = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

type Props<T> = T

type Select<Value = unknown> = (props: Props<Value>) => any;

const PersonSelect: Select<Person> = (props) => null //implementation is irrelavant

const TextSelect: Select<string> = (props) => null //implementation is irrelavant

type Filter<V = unknown> = {
  component: Select<V>,
  transformer: <T extends V>(value: T & V) => string
};


const builder = <V,>(
  component: Select<V>,
  transformer: (value: V) => string
): Filter<V> =>
  ({ component, transformer })

const filters = [
  builder(PersonSelect, (selected) => selected.name),
  builder(TextSelect, (selected) => selected)
]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBABRgJwM4HsB2cC8cDeoccAlgCYBccmArgLYBGKA3EdQIZ0xWpjImYA5qxABfUKEixEydFFQAeACoA%20XHCUTw0eAGUYAGxgBjMAoBq7AzXh4amANaZ0Ad0xq8ACiiz5VBL6KltYwKgCUuGrsmBAioMZYvIgoGJj6RqZU6SZmSGhYHnDegRE4arQGBnAA9NUkdFBGXJhg7GAkWKSopMjIhuwAbtFgWgmYSUowAB5g2Zlwc2a8-EKFxXKopeU0lTV1DU0wLW0d2CTdJL39Qy1aUvAAYiQGYCgW6vZOru7qhCDECQaWCOYCyhhyFhUABo2HxoqgAGboZBcZBUZRwaavTBkbrmFSeIYhKhKOAAMjg5i2cGWAkEoFEcRA8USYDgDBozzIKHUFihBLYgKgwJaYIyZnxMP%20cDh4yRKJQVEJVhsVCpkRpfDpoDCVCeLze%20MibE8%20DgQpFYChMuQ8PlqLgojCo1ZcARz1eaHUAG02ByuShPHlUotrZ5UODTDAyNSI%20LowA6TCcGBhKXEf0GbnITyTGahopxnLR2OR14x0AAXSAA)

Because `component` and `transformer` arguments are not the part of same data structure, it is easier to infer them and apply our type constraints.

[Here](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments), you can find more examples of type Inference on function arguments.