# Typescript 4.4 breaking tuple union inference

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
// Works fine in 4.3.5, not in 4.4.2

type ArgsTupleUnion<T> =
  | [obj: T, x: (arg: T) => void]
  | [y: (arg: number) => void];

function f<T>(...args: ArgsTupleUnion<T>) {}

f({ k: 15 }, (arg) => { // 4.3.5: arg is {k: number}, 4.4.2: arg is 'any'
  console.log(arg.k);
});

f((a: number) => {});


type ArgsTuple<T> =
  | [obj: T, x: (arg: T) => void]
  // | [y: (arg: number) => void];

function f2<T>(...args: ArgsTuple<T>) {}

f2({ k: 15 }, (arg) => { // Both 4.3.5 and 4.4.2: arg is {k: number}
  console.log(arg.k);
});
```

[Here's the code on TS Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/FAFwngDgpgBAggJwOYGcAqBXCAbKBVAOwEsB7AgHjQD4YBeYGGAHxgG0SAjAKwC4Y0ANDAAefABQBDZHzQBKOjQBuJIgBMAug2Zsw4qUj4EMAWw5QE82kpUaA3MGAAzDAQDGIUgRiPKVMQDpA-RQ+RFRMHHxiMl95AG8AXwdHMTiYAGs+AEYAVhgEoUlkSxo0gHoymAAWfwBmfxy+fRgiFBg4zJgjU3MC6v8agCYm5Ba2gHIJAjBxrVcyFBJcf2wSJCKkf3TZewSd5LFJQxMzCwV2vfsHcGh4ZHQsXF86LRZ2bhkhURgNmRKYZRqTSMCraVi6H76Y49M5WAE2dRXZxuDxkbyDXwBIL3UL3CJPajxJJOQapDLZPJ9Db-cqVABCJBAAAt+vU8lNVP0hiMkGN2p1uqckox5gRFstVut9Ft9pcgA) I'm not sure which change has made this stop working but it's preventing me from upgrading to 4.4. Anyone else who has run into this or has an idea for a workaround?

Comment: I have a similar (but not the same) problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69254779/infer-type-based-on-the-generic-type-of-a-sibling-property-in-typescript#comment122406960_69254779 tsplayground: tsplay.dev/Na0Mow   . I think it worth creating and issue and wait for official explanation

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the new [Control Flow Analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#control-flow-analysis-of-aliased-conditions-and-discriminants). However for a quick fix you could use `[y: (arg: T) => void]`

Comment: @captain-yossarian It does look similar but in your example changing to 4.3.5 doesn't seem to make a difference so I'd classify it as a separate issue.

Comment: @MuratKaragöz Thanks for the suggestion, seems like that will have to do for now.

Answer (score 0):

A possible work around would be to use functional overload

It seems that typescript is opting in for the more specific type number rather than tracking the number of elements in a given array.

```
type ArgsTuple<T> = [obj: T, x: (arg: T) => void];
type NumArrFun = [y: (arg: number) => void];

type ArgsTupleUnion<T> =
  | ArgsTuple<T>
  | NumArrFun;

function f<T>(...args: ArgsTuple<T>): void
function f<T>(...args: NumArrFun): void
function f<T>(...args: ArgsTupleUnion<T>) {}

f({ k: 15 }, (arg) => { // 4.3.5: arg is {k: number}, 4.4.2: arg is 'any'
  console.log(arg.k);
});

f((a: number) => {});
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwM4BUCuYA2EA8KB8UAvFANoD2ARgFYBcUKANFAB70AUAhovSgJTFCAN3IBLACYBdANwAoUJCgA5NAFt4cAGJoAdsTIgO3BPR1rKEOAKLCxUufPDR4ydFggBVHaPI68hIlkoKAAfWERUDGx-INDlNQ1tHQcAM10AY2AfPRT-dgA6QuMkehdI938%20ehEJWTSdTOyoXIICooj6FXU4LV0qqBrxOoys32a8wvzi0oi3bC9syqgAbwBfWTr2ZagAa3oARgBWKFXmLkRrQm2AemuoABZ8gGZ8w-pjKFEkFb2oM1ULHBTg98o8AEzvRCfb6cTBIchQADu5DgO1EOgQf3IiNi6V88Ow%20Uw5AQ5wQ%20R2fDkqypGxS7C4pnMlkuKxp0iAA)